# How to Receive Intents for Location

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have built a Broadcast receiver that I want to receive intents when other applications have got a location. To me clear this is so I can receive location updates when my app is not running. When I receive the location I start an intentService to update my db.

However I am unsure which intent filter to use in the manifest?

Is there a list of what intent filters I can use?

Comment: The list of intent filters you can use is here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#constants

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is use the [`LocationManager` requestLocationUpdates() method with a pending intent argument](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29). If you are using API version 8 or higher, the location provider you want to use is the [`PASSIVE_PROVIDER`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PASSIVE_PROVIDER) so that you get updates only when other activities update them.

You don't have to use a BroadcastReceiver in this situation, as the PendingIntent is called whenever the location changes.

Summing up, this is how you could implement this

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PassiveLocationActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            intent, 0);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 1000, 10.0f, pendingIntent);
```

and make sure you add the permission to your Manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

**WARNING:** doing this kind of thing can be very taxing on the battery. Make sure you set sane values for `minTime` and `minDistance`, and call `locationManager.removeUpdates(pendingIntent);` when you no longer need the updates.

Comment: I wanted to receive updates when my application is closed. So that's why I am using a broadcast receiver. So it is not possible for me to register the passive provider dynamically. This way I would not use any extra battery as I will just be receiving the location when other apps get it. I have updated the question to be clearer

Comment: I am not aware of a BroadcastReceiver for location updates. It may be intentional, as it mean lots of overhead because location can change very rapidly. Even with a receiver, you are still going to use more resources if you are doing something every time the location is updated anywhere. Why do you need location updates even when your app is not running?

Comment: yeah I fugured it out. The intents to receieve are definded within code. I was actually looking at this post. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

It explains why you might use this approach. In my case it wont use any extra resources appart from whever it take to change maximum 20 entry in an SQLite DB.